# Paginate ROOM entity with one to many relation (@Embedded and @Relation)

Tags: android-room, android-paging-3

I have a one to many relation of two entities. Is there a way to paginate ROOM database response using jetpacks Paging 3 library. Dao's return type would be `PagingSource<Int, List<TaskWithAttachmets>>`

```
data class TaskWithAttachmets(
    @Embedded
    val task: LocalTask,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "taskId",
        entityColumn = "taskId"
    )
    val attachments: List<LocalAttachmentsInfo>,
)
```

I'm getting following error at compile time

```
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (androidx.paging.PagingSource<java.lang.Integer, java.util.List<com.sample.database.entities.TaskWithAttachmets>>)
```